# Invoke Jenkins Restapi call from from webapi C#

Tags: api, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which takes 2 file parameters and a string. I am able to invoke them from curl however I want to know how to invoke from the c# backend?

Answer (score 1):

you can include nuget package `jenkinsnet` in your code.
DOcumentation & examples https://github.com/null511/Jenkins.NET

or you can use the jenkins rest api directly 
https://www.automatetheplanet.com/jenkins-csharp-api-triggering-builds/